# Clear way to change favicon in ImpressPages 4

Tags: favicon, impresspages

is there a clear way to change the favicon in ImpressPages4?

I Would use something like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/Theme/Bootstrapfree/assets/icon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/Theme/Bootstrapfree/assets/icon.png">
<link type="image/png" href="http://example.com/Theme/Bootstrapfree/assets/icon.png">
```

it seems that: `Ip/Response/Layout.php` sets the favicon, which is called bei `Ip/Internal/PageAssets.php`

But is it possible to change it inside an Theme?
I found no config regarding on favicon.

Or is it not recommended to Change the Favicon?
Sure i could replace the favicon.ico file under / but thats isn't really comfortable.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin way of doing https://github.com/impresspages-plugins/Favicon